# Exclude / ignore weekends in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a query that groups text together and their start and end date, i want to exclude/ignore the weekends.

In this example 11-12 and 18-19 april are the weekends

```
 create table t ( d date, v varchar2(10));
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-10', 'ne');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-13', 'ne');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-14', 'jm');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-15', 'ne');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-16', 'jm');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-17', 'jm');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-20', 'jm');
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-21', 'jm');
```

and the query

```
select min(d), max(d), v
from (
    select d, v, 
        sum( gc) over (partition by v order by d) g
    from (
        select d, v, 
            (case (d - lag(d) over ( partition by v order by d) )
                when 1 then 0
                else 1
             end) gc
        from t
    )
) group by v, g
order by min(d), v
```

I made a SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662918/1

Output

```
MIN(D)           max(D)           v
2015-04-10 - 2015-04-13 - ne
2015-04-14 - 2015-04-14 - jm
2015-04-15 - 2015-04-15 - ne
2015-04-16 - 2015-04-21 - jm
```

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is great.  However, we should be able to understand your question *without* having to leave Stack Overflow.  Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, explain what you mean by weekends and holidays.

Comment: Thanks, it's now in my post

Comment: And what is the output you want for the sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query with small modification in `case ... when` excluding weekend days:

```
select min(d), max(d), v
  from (
    select d, v, sum( gc) over (partition by v order by d) g
      from (
        select d, v, 
            case when d-lag(d) over (partition by v order by d) 
                          = decode(trunc(d, 'iw') - d, 0, 3, 1)
                 then 0
                 else 1
            end gc
          from t)) 
  group by v, g
  order by min(d), v
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662918/9)</sup>

Recursive solution is possible too, but I suspect that this is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a filter like:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(d, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

For example,

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE t ( d DATE, v VARCHAR2(10));
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-10', 'ne');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-11', 'ne'); --> Added new row for demo
    insert into t values (date '2015-04-12', 'ne'); --> Added new row for demo
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-13', 'ne');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-14', 'jm');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-15', 'ne');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-16', 'jm');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-17', 'jm');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-18', 'jm'); --> Added new row for demo
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-19', 'jm'); --> Added new row for demo
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-20', 'jm');
    INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2015-04-21', 'jm');

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

D         V
--------- ----------
10-APR-15 ne
11-APR-15 ne
12-APR-15 ne
13-APR-15 ne
14-APR-15 jm
15-APR-15 ne
16-APR-15 jm
17-APR-15 jm
18-APR-15 jm
19-APR-15 jm
20-APR-15 jm

D         V
--------- ----------
21-APR-15 jm

12 rows selected.
```

**Test case**

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM t
  3  WHERE TO_CHAR(d, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN');

D         V
--------- ----------
10-APR-15 ne
13-APR-15 ne
14-APR-15 jm
15-APR-15 ne
16-APR-15 jm
17-APR-15 jm
20-APR-15 jm
21-APR-15 jm

8 rows selected.
```

So, using the above logic in your query you could get your desired output.

**Modified query**

```
SQL> SELECT MIN(d),
  2    MAX(d),
  3    v
  4  FROM
  5    (SELECT d,
  6      v,
  7      SUM( gc) over (partition BY v order by d) g
  8    FROM
  9      (SELECT d,
 10        v,
 11        (
 12        CASE (d - lag(d) over ( partition BY v order by d) )
 13          WHEN 1
 14          THEN 0
 15          ELSE 1
 16        END) gc
 17      FROM t
 18      )
 19    )
 20  WHERE TO_CHAR(d, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
 21  GROUP BY v,
 22    g
 23  ORDER BY MIN(d),
 24    v;

MIN(D)    MAX(D)    V
--------- --------- ----------
10-APR-15 13-APR-15 ne
14-APR-15 14-APR-15 jm
15-APR-15 15-APR-15 ne
16-APR-15 21-APR-15 jm

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, in my SQLFiddle it still doesn't ignore the weekends: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662918/8

Comment: @MeesvanZ if you mean Saturdays and Sundays, then first of all, you don't have them in the setup. And thus,  your output only shows weekdays(which is correct). In my answer, I have explicitly added the missing rows, and then derived your desired output.

Comment: I have no rights to edit the database, i can only query 'read' functions

Comment: @MeesvanZ You don't have to edit anything at all. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b8e9/1 Do you see any weekend days in the output?

Comment: the weekend days arent in my database like, without these dates your query isn't working

Comment: @MeesvanZ Are you sure the query is not working? It's working for me, and also perfectly in SQL Fiddle, look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/970c1/1

Comment: The dates April, 10 to April, 13 are separated, in your previous SQL Fiddle it was showing the correct output: sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b8e9/1